# Angular2 applying dynamic css class fails

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

I have an expansion panel group and I am trying to appy a css class to the active panel:

```
<mdl-expansion-panel-group>
    <mdl-expansion-panel *ngFor="let task of tasks" [ngClass]="{'active': task.id == selectedTask}">
        <mdl-expansion-panel-header>
            <mdl-expansion-panel-header-list-content><h6>{{task.what_task}} {{task.id}}</h6></mdl-expansion-panel-header-list-content>
        </mdl-expansion-panel-header>
        <mdl-expansion-panel-content>
            <mdl-expansion-panel-body>

                <button mdl-button mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-colored (click)="selectTaskToEdit(task)">
                    Edit
                </button>

            </mdl-expansion-panel-body>
        </mdl-expansion-panel-content>
    </mdl-expansion-panel>
</mdl-expansion-panel-group>
```

css class `active` has a background color set to say yellow. In my component I am printing `console.log(this.selectedTask==task.id)` which comes out true, however my class is not being applied.

My component:

```
  selectTaskToEdit(task){

    this.task=task;
    this.selectedTask=task.id;
    console.log(this.selectedTask==task.id)
  }
```

and css:

```
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

**UPDATE**: I could solve it using `[style.background-color]="task.id == selectedTask ? 'yellow': null "` however I would like to know if there is a correct way of doing with ngClass

Comment: Can you show us `selectTaskToEdit` code? where you're setting up `selectedTask`?

Comment: where did you specify `active`  css class?

Comment: `background-color: yellow !important;` could you please try and add `!important` in the end and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[style.background-color]="task.id == selectedTask ? 'yellow': null"`

or

`[class.active]="task.id == selectedTask"`

is the only way to make it, because `mdl-expansion-panel` has own [host class expressions](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext/blob/master/src/components/expansion-panel/expansion-panel.component.ts#L103), which overrides yours `[ngClass]`.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xQiRfk2rnsZbtPbXHweZ) is the example plnkr.

Comment: [class.active]="task.id == selectedTask" has no effect :( however the first approach works. I figured it out but will accept it an answer